# How to iterate over a ctypes array in python?

Tags: python, ctypes

```
a = ((c_char*2)*2)(('a','b'),('c','d'))
a
Out::<__main__.c_char_Array_2_Array_2 at 0x47da8c8>

b = [cast(i, c_char_p) for i in a] 
b

Out::[c_char_p('abcd'), c_char_p('cd')]
```

How can I iterate properly so  that I get an output

```
Out::[c_char_p('ab'), c_char_p('cd')]
```

Comment: `c_char_p` pointers have no length. The `value` is a null-terminated string. If there's no null in allocated memory, this will actually segfault. What's the end goal here?

Comment: I get this type of pattern while reading a file.(Fortran unformatted). I am trying to read a record of length n which has each element of type (char*8). I need to iterate over it

Comment: @eryksun I get this type of pattern while reading a file.(Fortran unformatted). I am trying to read a record of length n which has each element of type (char*8). I need to iterate over it

Comment: You can just read a record from the file and parse it using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module. But if it's just n 8-byte string elements, then you probably don't even need the struct module.

Comment: @eryksun yeah I know. Infact I have done parsing already with struct and numpy. However after going through online articles I see it might be possible to use multiprocessing with ctypes so I want to figure out this way. More-ever this might also help me to integrate some c/fortran code directly without knowing much about them.So I want to figure this out